# How can I make my UWP app Fast as Microsoft UWP apps(Mail, Groove Music)?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to make my uwp app as fast as possible like Microsoft apps. Whenever I open the Groove Music it is always ready to show me the list of songs even the page I visited last time. It doesn't load for a moment. What's the mechanism behind that?  How can I make my app fast like that? actually, I want my app to be always ready to show a list of items in listview whenever I open my app.

Comment: Microsoft doesn't open source his project but you can get pretty get many basic ideas from the apps' code on GitHub, mostly from samples.

Comment: hrm not im not sure why this is getting upvoted, its not really an answerable question

Comment: You just need to have something like a TEMPORARY file with the last status of your app. You can save anything there, to be more easy, use serialization. Btw groove sucks... it's terrible and slow

Comment: Have you set specific perf goals, and have you measured your code to see which bits are stopping you from reaching your goals?

Comment: Hard to be accurate about it, but I'd say at least ten skilled programmers and a handful of threads.

Comment: I think the OP is looking specifically for app launch performance, to get the near-instant launch experience that some UWP apps provide. See my answer for the "one line fix" (famous last words): CoreApplication.EnablePrelaunch(true)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The feature you are looking for is called Prelaunch. Most Microsoft apps opt into prelaunch which will make them eligible to get background-launched (and then suspended) opportunistically by the OS, based on some heuristics. Then when the user launches the app, the OS will just need to resume them from suspended state which is much faster than launching them cold. The OS will prioritize apps that the user frequently launches, so you may not see an immediate effect, but over time the user will get better launch times.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-app-prelaunch

Comment: You are right. I have recently learned that multithread programming for restoring data will also help me to boost my app lunch fast. So that my UI will not wait for data.

Answer (score 1):

Check this document. It will make your app really fast like pure Microsoft apps. I am an enthusiastic .net developer. I figured out this.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/best-practices-for-your-app-s-startup-performance

Open properties of the project solution. Go to the build section. Then enable **Compile with .NET Native tool chain**

Select **release** instead of **debug** and then select run or the green button (Local Machine). It will take time and you will see the result after that.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]